# Is there a method or an addon where I can use G,R,S with the preview screen of the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm talking about the feature in Openshot and sony vegas where you can select the items in the preview screen and drag/move/rotate/scale them.

In VSE, it seems that I need to select the item in the timeline and press the N-Panel. Then, play with the properties. But I can't do this from the viewport as far as I know. There could be a method or an addon that I don't know about. I just want to use it as If it is a 2D viewport where I move items as if they are nodes or something similar.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install this add-on and open the toolbar in the preview:
https://github.com/zeograd/VSE_Transform_Tools

[image]

Comment: It's good but it doesn't work with blender 2.9x.

Comment: The default version is for 2.92+  If you're using an earlier version of Blender 2.9x you need a different version.  See the comments in the github page for details.

Comment: Just before answering I tested it against 2.93 and the major functions works fine here(some functions haven't been updated yet).

Comment: @tintwotin Well, I think I'll ask another question about why it doesn't work for me lol. I'll do my research first.